# Move a div when another div is hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
div#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

div#menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

div#recenter {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  bottom: 180px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

div#geolocation {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  bottom: 125px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="recenter">Re-center</div>
  <div id="geolocation">My address is : 3958 Heron Way - Oregon 97351</div>
  <div id="menu" onclick="document.getElementById('geolocation').style.display = 'none';">MENU (CLICK ME)</div>
</div>
```

Currently, when I hide the `#geolocation` block in javascript, the `#recenter` button does not move.

What I want is that when I run the following jQuery command: 
`$('#geolocation').hide();` 
(or in js : `document.getElementById('geolocation').style.display = 'none';`) 
the `#recenter` button moves to the bottom (where the `#geolocation` block was located)

How to do ?

Comment: Why is everything positioned absolutely?

Comment: @Paulie_D Because, it is the easiest way (for me) to position elements between them.

Comment: it is only easy at first glance. if you want to move items and let them be dependant on each other you get into problems (just like you had with your question) don't use position absolute unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't position elements the absolutely, take advantage of flexbox layout and alignment options.

```css
div#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div#menu {
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div#recenter {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

div#geolocation {
  line-height: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="recenter">Re-center</div>
  <div id="geolocation">My address is : 3958 Heron Way - Oregon 97351</div>
  <div id="menu" onclick="document.getElementById('geolocation').style.display = 'none';">MENU (CLICK ME)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to me, and in my case, Flexbox layout and alignment options are indeed the most suitable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the geolocation, and hide it, you can also move the recenter button to the bottom.
It's not a very nice way to do this, but it works.

```css
div#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 500px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

div#menu {
  position: absolute;
  height: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 0px;
  line-height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

div#recenter {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  bottom: 180px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

div#geolocation {
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
  bottom: 125px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="recenter">Re-center</div>
  <div id="geolocation">My address is : 3958 Heron Way - Oregon 97351</div>
  <div id="menu" onclick="document.getElementById('geolocation').style.display = 'none';document.getElementById('recenter').style.bottom = '125px';">MENU (CLICK ME)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

wrap the geolocation and recenter div within a div and give it to them a class. then use calc and flex to achieve your requirement like below. don't need to use `position` and `bottom` CSS it's a very bad practice for this kind of situation. Happy Solution :)

```css
div#content{
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid black;
   height:500px;
   bottom:0px;
}
div#menu{
   position:absolute;
   height:125px;
   width:100%;
   border:1px solid black;
   bottom:0px;
   line-height:125px;
   text-align:center;
}

  #recenter{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  max-width:120px;
  border-radius:30px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  }

#geolocation{
    line-height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin:10px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.upper_div{
    height: calc(100% - 125px);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
 <div class=upper_div>
     <div id="recenter">Re-center</div>
 <div id="geolocation">My address is : 3958  Heron Way - Oregon 97351</div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu" onclick="document.getElementById('geolocation').style.display = 'none';">MENU</div>
</div>
```